# how to use variables in SQLite definition

Tags: python, sqlite

when I try to select rows by a date as variable I get None as result

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM ES_F WHERE date = {};'.format('2017-10-23'))
----> None
```

when I put the same date inside the SQL definition it works fine and I get the row I wanted.

```
c.execute("""SELECT * FROM ES_F WHERE date = '2017-10-23';""")
----> ('2017-10-23', '09:27', 567, 'Mon', 2576.5, 2574.0, 2572.75, 2577.25, 2572.0, 2577.25, 2061.0, 159300, 3096574, 'ESZ7')
```

I would like to use as variable though because I have to use it recursively.
Any idea of why it does not work? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* use value conversion to `repr` with the `.format` method:

```
'SELECT * FROM ES_F WHERE date = {!r};'.format('2017-10-23')
```

Or make the single-quotes part of the string:

```
'SELECT * FROM ES_F WHERE date = {};'.format("'2017-10-23'")
```

But *really*, best practice is not to use string-interpolation at all, because that makes you vulnerable to SQL injection.

As the [docs state](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html):

> Instead, use the DB-API’s parameter substitution. Put `?` as a
>   placeholder wherever you want to use a value, and then provide a tuple
>   of values as the second argument to the cursor’s `execute()` method.

So use:

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM ES_F WHERE date = ?;', ('2017-10-23',))
```

Comment: spot on thanks! the only one thing is that instead of a semicolon I needed to use a comma only

Comment: @user3755529 whoops, yeah, that was an editing error.